# How to set element height based on height of two other elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need a component's height to be the sum of the heights of two other components on the page. I am using React and Typescript in my application. The elements are responsive so their heights will not be constant. I have tried setting refs on the two components and then calculating the 'clientHeight' value of the components but I am facing a lot of issues with this. Is there a better way to do this in React?

Comment: is it possible for you to share working example?

Comment: sharing an example of code you considered or have tried will help make this question more clear

Comment: You probably don't want to use refs here though - you probably want to have your components in a parent/child structure that makes it easy for the parent (third) component to keep track of the sum of the heights of the (other) two child components.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this via JS - setting refs etc and then grabbing height, however you'd need to recalculate this every time the content changed, or the window size changed etc etc..

I don't know the exact layout you're trying to achieve,but could you not use regular CSS? either `flex` or `grid` should be able to accomplish this

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1fr, 2);
}

.leftCol {
  background: red;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row: 1 /  span 2;
}

.rightTopCol {
  background: green;
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.rightBottomCol {
  background: blue;
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">

  <div class="leftCol">
    <p>content content content</p>
  </div>

  <div class="rightTopCol">
    <p>content content content</p>
    <p>content content content</p>
    <p>content content content</p>
    <p>content content content</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="rightBottomCol">
    <p>content content content</p>
    <p>content content content</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

or

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  
}

.leftCol {
  padding: 5px;
  background: red;
}

.right {
  background: yellow;
  }

.rightTopCol {
  padding: 5px;
  background: green;
}

.rightBottomCol {
  padding: 5px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">

  <div class="leftCol">
    <p>content content content</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="right">
    <div class="rightTopCol">
      <p>content content content</p>
      <p>content content content</p>
      <p>content content content</p>
      <p>content content content</p>
    </div>
  
    <div class="rightBottomCol">
      <p>content content content</p>
      <p>content content content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  

</div>
```